# Nodejs : Require libraries from other files than server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my application folder structure for a node REST server.

```
MyApp
|
|__node_modules
|  |__lodash
|
|__routes
|  |__routes.js
|
|__server.js
```

In server.js I am able to require the loadsh library by doing

```
var _l = require("lodash");
```

**(Problem 1)**

But the variable _l is not accessible in the code of routes.js.

**(Problem 2)**

So I tried to require lodash from my routes.js, but node isnt able to resolve path to it.
I tried adding "./" , "../" but it doesnt work.

So, is there any way if the var _l create in server.js be accessible everywhere else, and if not , what is the proper way to include modules in files(not in root folder) other than server.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `var _l = require("lodash");`.

Node will search for modules recursively, all the way to `/node_modules` or `C:\node_modules`

Comment: So it means there was no need to try "../"   ... Ohhh

Comment: Technically you can do that, by `require('../node_modules/lodash');`, but that's stupid and bad form.

Comment: Yes. It works directly, I am wondering why it erred the first time I tried directly. It made me ask a question! but , thank you.